# Windows service application insights mark request telemetry as failed

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a long running windows service that runs a Queue listener. I have referenced ApplicationInsights nuget packages and set up dependency collector. It works perfect without any line of code related to Application Insights inside message handling. Inside Azure I can see that Request is called 'Process' and has all Traces and Dependencies attached correctly.

Now I need to mark some of requests as Failed. How do I access a specific RequestTelemetry to set it's properties while handling a message?

This is how I launch my telemetry. I call Start method when windows service starts:
   public class TelemetryApp
    {
        private static DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule _dependencyTrackingTelemetryModule;

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        var appInsightsConfiguration = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;

        appInsightsConfiguration.InstrumentationKey = SettingsHelper.AppInsightsInstrumentationKey;
        appInsightsConfiguration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
        appInsightsConfiguration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());

        DependencyTracking.Initialize(appInsightsConfiguration);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _dependencyTrackingTelemetryModule.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally I would say use a [telemetry intializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer). Thats the place to inspect and modify an item. Or add custom properties to it. In your case I do not know if you can identity the item you want to mark as failed. How does your code look like and exactly what packages did you use? You really did not have to create a RequestTelemetry using code??

Comment: @PeterBons, I have added a bit of code - this is roughly the only code I need to get everything going out of the box.
Telemetry initializer is kinda like a static thing and I will not be able to map n-th request to its telemetry.

Comment: I know that in asp.net core you can do something like `var requestTelemetry = HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();         requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("key", "set from inside controller");` but I don't think that is applicable to your situation. I am suprised your app creates a root request automatically, not sure how you can get to it though. Obviously there is no `HttpContext` you can use but maybe there is something similair.

Comment: What is the condition to evalaute that a request is failed or not?

Comment: Every message that I process consumes has 'ExpiresAt' property. If in the end of execution of a handler NOW>Message.ExpiresAt than I need to mark it as failed. This is specific to what we do, but condition is pretty strict.
Yes, I agree, I would love to access some sort of ProcessContext but I don't see it anywhere :)